# extend dates of a data.frames in R?

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse, lubridate, extends

I would like to `extend` the `Datetime` of `DF1` up to the `End_date` with the last value of variable `x` being repeated till `End_date`. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

DF1 <- data.frame(Datetime = seq(ymd_hms("2011-01-01 00:00:00"), to= ymd_hms("2011-01-10 00:00:00"), by = "hour"),
                X = runif(217, 5,10))

End_date <- "2011-01-15 00:00:00"
```

Comment: (1) It would help immensely to provide sample output. (2) I suggest that a small reprex would not need over 2000 rows of random data, can you try to make it something a lot smaller? It might make "expected output" a bit easier to represent.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans - I give it some more thoughts and revised my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `complete` with `fill` :

```
library(tidyr)
DF1 %>%
   complete(Datetime = seq(min(Datetime), as.POSIXct(End_date), 'hour')) %>%
   fill(X)
```

Or using only `complete` we can pass last value of `DF1$X` in `fill`.

```
DF1 %>%
  complete(Datetime = seq(min(Datetime), as.POSIXct(End_date), 'hour'), 
           fill = list(X = DF1$X[nrow(DF1)]))
```

Comment: I think addresses more what the data suggests they need, nice.

Answer (score 2):

Sample data, only a few rows required to demonstrate:

```r
set.seed(123)
DF1 <- data.frame(
  Datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 00:00:00"), to = as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 03:00:00"), by = "hour"),
  X = runif(4, 5, 10)
)
End_date <- as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 07:00:00")
DF1
#              Datetime        X
# 1 2011-01-01 00:00:00 6.437888
# 2 2011-01-01 01:00:00 8.941526
# 3 2011-01-01 02:00:00 7.044885
# 4 2011-01-01 03:00:00 9.415087
```

The add-on frame is just another call to `data.frame`/`seq`, using the last value from `DF1`:

```r
DF1aug <- data.frame(
  Datetime = seq(from = DF1$Datetime[nrow(DF1)], to = End_date, by="hour")[-1],
  X = DF1$X[nrow(DF1)]
)
DF1aug
#              Datetime        X
# 1 2011-01-01 04:00:00 9.415087
# 2 2011-01-01 05:00:00 9.415087
# 3 2011-01-01 06:00:00 9.415087
# 4 2011-01-01 07:00:00 9.415087
```

This can be augmented easily to the first with `rbind`:

```r
rbind(DF1, DF1aug) 
#              Datetime        X
# 1 2011-01-01 00:00:00 6.437888
# 2 2011-01-01 01:00:00 8.941526
# 3 2011-01-01 02:00:00 7.044885
# 4 2011-01-01 03:00:00 9.415087
# 5 2011-01-01 04:00:00 9.415087
# 6 2011-01-01 05:00:00 9.415087
# 7 2011-01-01 06:00:00 9.415087
# 8 2011-01-01 07:00:00 9.415087
```

If you're using tidyverse, then all of this with:

```r
library(dplyr)
DF1 %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  do(data.frame(
    Datetime = seq(from = .$Datetime, to = End_date, by="hour")[-1],
    X = .$X
  )) %>%
  bind_rows(DF1, .)
```